# How to start another addon from a kodi addon

Tags: python, add-on, kodi

I Made a simple video addon for kodi which runs fine. I added a “whats on tv now” section and would like to be able to start the pvr simple iptv cliënt - at the desired station. I tried finding information on how to start another addon but cant seem to find anything.

Someone to direct me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You can try RunPlugin()

```
xbmc.executebuiltin('RunPlugin(plugin://plugin.video.youtube/channel/UCorjdnnxED9FZmur8avvGgQ/?addon_id=plugin.video.example)')
```